# Using different Provisioning Profile to submit app iPhone

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning-profile

we have an app currently released on the App Store with the application-identifier "AAAAAAAAAA.com.domain.AppName", but the Provisioning Profile that we used until now is connected to the App ID "AAAAAAAAAA.com.*".

We now want to enable the Push Notification Services, so we created another App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile connected to the App ID "BBBBBBBBBB.com.domain.AppName".

Is it possible to release the app with this App ID and that this release will overwrite the current app?
If it will not, what is the correct way to achieve our goal?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

There is no problem if you change prefix App ID and provisioning profile, but there are some technologies based on prefix (like keychain access) will not work after change.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1726/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

For push-notification there will have new additional distribution (also development )provisioning profile when you enable push-nofication with your current **app id**. So, both are different. Your **new app** will replace on **current app**

Comment: Hi, thank you. Are there any problem if the teamID are differents? As you can see we have now AAAAAAAA and the new provisioning profile use BBBBBBB.

Comment: OK Jamil, thank you. 

Moreover, about this topic I report a link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html